# Excel - Getting the first cell after which a continous range meets criteria

Tags: excel, range, match, formula

I have a relatively big database in Excel 2016 describing the costs of changing to a new product after two years.
The old product (Product A) has to be repaired after every *n* uses, which makes the cost curve look like a strairway. The new product (Product B) has no such costs, so in this case the curve would be linear. The two curves are divergent, but only slightly.
By comparing the two products, B is always cheaper directly after repairing Product A, because of the repair costs. Over the *n* time Product A has only lower costs, so until just before repair, Product A is a bit cheaper.
[Price comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z905o.png)

**I have the cost savings in a column, and I am looking for the row of the last negative number, after which in a range of *n* cells all the numbers are positive.**

I`ve tried to experiment with MATCH so far, but it stops after the first number is found.
e.g.:

A1
-45
15
-60
-20
30
15
40
50

Assuming, that n = 3 and -45 is in cell A1, I would like a formula, whitch gives me A4 as a result (as the following numbers in the next 3 cells are all positive).
MATCH stops at A1 (or A2 if looking for positive numbers).

Can it be done with an (array) formula? How?
A bit more generally: how can I "push" a condition check for a range through a whole column/array?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without Array, you could do it by adding a column with the row number:

```
A1  B1    
-45 1   
15  2    
-60 3   
-20 4   
[...]
```

And using the formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/(A1:A8<0);B1:B8)
```

This would give you the row number (column B) of the first negative result starting from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the tip. I was able to mathematically define a lower envelope for the function describing my values, so I could calculate the point where it crosses the x axis. That solved the problem.

Thank you again.

Comment: Great that you found your own answer! Please upvote if you found my/an answer helpful ;)